# How to combine Jarray?

Tags: c#, arrays, json

c#
I'm going to combine Jarray.
Each Jarray has a common id, a Jobject.
I'm going to make a json file based on "id". What should I do?

Jarray 1

```
[
    {
        "id" : "222",
        "name" : "second"
    },
    {
        "id" : "111",
        "name" : "first"
    },
    {
        "id" : "333",
        "name" : "third"
    }
]
```

Jarray 2

```
[
    {
        "id" : "111",
        "info" : "one one one"
    },
    {
        "id" : "222",
        "info" : "two two two"
    },
    {
        "id" : "333",
        "info" : "three three three"
    }
]
```

Jarray 3

```
[
    {
        "id" : "333",
        "number" : "3"
        "call" : "three"
    },
    {
        "id" : "222",
        "number" : "2"
        "call" : "two"
    },
    {
        "id" : "111",
        "number" : "1"
        "call" : "one"
    }
]
```

Comment: Personally I've had great learning experiences from diving head first into the deep waters albeit starting with a greater basic knowledge. Nonetheless I don't really see anything wrong with OP's approach. Personally I avoid JArray and those other J-types whenever possible, but I don't see how the question is bad. One think we might be able to agree is that the quality of the question is not the best, but I'm here to help, not to deter people asking for help to ever ask again.

Answer (score 0):

A class which holds all the properties:

```
class NameInfoNumberCall
{
    internal string ID { get; set; }
    internal string Name { get; set; }
    internal string Info { get; set; }
    internal string Number { get; set; }
    internal string Call { get; set; }
}
```

Code to populate the objects based on the JArrays. Simply loop over all the items, access the properties and store it in the object:

```
static void Main()
{
    var jarray1 = JArray.Parse("[{\"id\":\"222\",\"name\":\"second\"},{\"id\":\"111\",\"name\":\"first\"},{\"id\":\"333\",\"name\":\"third\"}]");
    var jarray2 = JArray.Parse("[{\"id\":\"111\",\"info\":\"oneoneone\"},{\"id\":\"222\",\"info\":\"twotwotwo\"},{\"id\":\"333\",\"info\":\"threethreethree\"}]");
    var jarray3 = JArray.Parse("[{\"id\":\"333\",\"number\":\"3\",\"call\":\"three\"},{\"id\":\"222\",\"number\":\"2\",\"call\":\"two\"},{\"id\":\"111\",\"number\":\"1\",\"call\":\"one\"}]");

    var infos = new Dictionary<string, NameInfoNumberCall>();
    foreach (JObject o in jarray1)
    {
        var info = new NameInfoNumberCall();
        info.ID = (string)o["id"];
        info.Name = (string)o["name"];
        infos.Add(info.ID, info);
    }

    foreach (JObject o in jarray2)
    {
        infos[(string)o["id"]].Info = (string)o["info"];
    }

    foreach (JObject o in jarray3)
    {
        infos[(string)o["id"]].Number = (string)o["number"];
        infos[(string)o["id"]].Call = (string)o["call"];
    }

    // do something with the data
}
```

Comment: your my hero your my angel your my all of things.... thank you sir my love

Comment: @ggumini: if this answer solves your problem, you can mark it as the accepted answer using the checkmark. Others will then know that no more help is needed.